# Mouse over option in select tag

Tags: javascript, html

Please suggest me a solution for my problem. I have a html **select** tag. When i mouse over on any option of select tag, it has to show an image on mouse over. How can i do it??

Comment: Where should be the image shown? Under the cursor? Does the image shown changes based no the hovered option?

Comment: @dzejkej yes, i want image under the cursor and it has to show based on mouse over.

Comment: @Amaan I tried with css background image option. But i didn't get anything

Comment: Where do you want the image to be shown?

Comment: did you tried anything which is not working?, as an idea how can you develop : you need to write a mouseover event/function for each of the option under that select and do the action as you wish.

Comment: Be more specific. Is it the same image for all options? Or is it an option-specific image?

Comment: No it is not same for all options. It is option specific

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code you've already tried. Without this it'll be difficult for anyone to constructively help you.

Comment: Do you need it in a form of listbox or combobox/dropdown? Because it looks to me that only listbox will work. If you must emulate combobox functionality then you probably need to create own widget :/.

Comment: @RAVITEJA, please take some time to read through the [faq], and then post some code. As it stands we aren't able to properly answer your question until you give us more information.

Answer (score 6):

According to the w3c spec, mouseover event is not supported by the option element.

There is no solution your requirement except to develop a custom drop down control.

Comment: mouseover event is working with option tag in mozilla firefox

Comment: @RAVITEJA SATYAVADA: Regrettably this is not true anymore. In Firefox 68.2.0esr onmouseover does *not* work anymore for select options.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by placing the `select` in a wrapping `DIV` which *does* see `mouseover` events. When the cursor enters the `select`, the wrapper `DIV` sees it, finds which `option` is selected, pulls its description, and displays it.

```js
function clearParamDescr( ) {
    // Description
    descriptionBox.innerHTML = '';
}   


function describeSelectParam( wrapDiv) {
    var innerSelect = wrapDiv.children[0];
    var selectedOption = innerSelect.options[innerSelect.selectedIndex];
    var descrTxt = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-descr');
    descriptionBox.innerHTML = descrTxt;
}
```

```html
    <div onmouseover="describeSelectParam(this)" onmouseout="clearParamDescr();" >
        <select id="locApplSel">
            <option value="F" data-descr="Used in an industrial environment">Factory
            <option value="L" data-descr="Used in a research or development lab">Laboratory
            <option value="R" data-descr="Used in homes">Residence
            <option value="V" data-descr="Used in a car, truck, boat, airplane, or other vehicle.">Vehicle
        </select>
    </div>
  <div id="descriptionBox"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the mouseover will not respond to the cursor moving over the dropdown's options unless the DIV is as large as the whole dropdown including the options.

Answer (score -1):

OnMouseover event for option works only in firefox and doesnt work in IE.
For IE, either use JQuery or use onMouseover for select tag

Answer (score -1):

You can simply solve your problem using the answer in the question below. There **are a two ways** of solving mouse events problem with `select option` on pure JS

[Mouse over option in select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342048/mouse-over-option-in-select-tag?noredirect=1&lq=1)

One of the way - is to make the select element with options in the form of `<div>` selector with `<buttons>` or `<li>` list inside. The introdusing of how it work you can see on my CodePen project-page below:
https://codepen.io/Sviatoslav_FrontEnd/pen/PQbBYQ

Answer (score -3):

You can do some thing like

```
<select title="This is a select">
<option value="blah blah" onmouseover="window.status=this.value" title="blah blah">item 1</option>
<option value="hello" onmouseover="window.status=this.value" title="hello">item 2</option>
<option value="hi" onmouseover="window.status=this.value" title="hi">item 3</option>
</select>
```

refer to the [mouseover](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-33745.html) for more

Comment: HTML ELEMENT OPTION <select> <option> </option> </select>

Comment: your solution is nice. But it is showing hint at select it self. Not for option tag

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Even setting it to a simple `alert()` won't work

Comment: This answer may not have helped the original questioner but it helped me realize that I could indeed use the title attribute with a SELECT element to get a mouse-over message for a dropdown list, so thanks...