# $(this) doesn't select child element in a delegated event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, this, selector

I have a select element with dynamically created options:

```js
$("#parent-id").append($('<option class="child-class" value="option1"> Option1 </option>'))

$("#parent-id").append($('<option class="child-class" value="option2"> Option2 </option>'))

//Try replacing ".child-class" with $(".child-class")
$("#parent-id").on("mouseover" , ".child-class" ,function(){
    var selectedOption = $(this).val();
    console.log(selectedOption)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="parent-id">

</select>
```

I want to get the value of each option on mouseover and run a function that does something with that value:

```
$("#parent-id").on("mouseover" , $(".child-class") ,function(){
    var selectedOption = $(this).val();
    console.log(selectedOption)
})
```

but right now selectedOption is the value of the parent element('select'), not the child ('option')!

How can I change the code to get the value of option elements?

UPDATE: added the code snippet. If I use ".child-class" instead of $(".child-class") nothing happens!

Comment: The second parameter to `.on()` should be just `".child-class"`, not `$(".child-class")`

Comment: It actually was correct in my original code, still not working.

Comment: When does the posted JavaScript code run? If it happens before the DOM is finished, nothing will happen. You'd be better off with `$(document).on("mouseover", "#parent-id .child-class", function ...)` for that reason

Comment: The Javascript runs right after the closing body tag. When I remove jquery $() from the .child-class then nothing happens on mouseover. With jquery selector, it logs the value of parent element!

Comment: Ah. Well according to MDN an `<option>` element doesn't trigger mouse events like "mouseover".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mouse over option in select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342048/mouse-over-option-in-select-tag)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342048/mouse-over-option-in-select-tag

Comment: Ahh! that should be it, thanks guys